# need to get reference to xml node from other node attribute

Tags: entity-framework, xpath

When you serialize object in Entity Framework only the first instance of that object gets serialized, after that references to the same object will point to the first instance. I can't get the right xpath to get a handle on the first instance so I can read it's properties. For example, let's say I have this xml:

```xml
<a:root>
<a:truck>
    <a:truck>
        <a:name>truck1</a:name>
        <a:tire>
            <a:tire z:Id="i1">
                <a:height>35</a:height>
                <a:width>12.5</a:width>
            </a:tire>
        </a:tire>
    </a:truck>
    <a:truck>
        <a:name>truck2</a:name>
        <a:tire>
            <a:tire z:Ref="i1" />
        </a:tire>
    </a:truck>
</a:truck>
</a:root>
```

I'm looping through truck nodes and I want to get the tire height. In the first case it's pretty straightforward, I can do something like:

```
<xsl:value-of select="a:tire/a:tire/a:height" />
```

but when I get to the second truck node the tire node is just a reference to the first tire node because they are in fact the identical tire object.

The part I'm having trouble with is coming up with the xpath that will read in the `z:Ref` attribute value, and if it exists get the node it points to and use that, otherwise use the node that is fully serialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first define a key:

```
<xsl:key name="ref" match="a:tire" use="@z:Id"/>
```

then instead of `<xsl:value-of select="a:tire/a:tire/a:height" />` you can use

```
<xsl:value-of select="a:tire/a:tire[not(@z:Ref)]/a:height | key('ref', a:tire/a:tire/@z:Ref)/a:height" />
```

Comment: That was exactly what I needed. The only snag was remembering to add the namespace:
    xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/